# Why actions can not be done on match groups when using replace operator in powershell?

Tags: powershell, replace, operators

Why when I execute following script:

```
'abc abc abc' -replace '\w+', '$0 abc'.ToUpper()
```

I get `abc ABC abc ABC abc ABC` instead of `ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC`?

Moreover, if I execute

```
'abc abc abc' -replace '\w+', '$0 abc'.ToCharArray()
```

I get `$ 0   a b c $ 0   a b c $ 0   a b c`

Is this possible to make some actions with match groups?

Comment: the replacement string is being worked on BEFORE the replacement takes place. [*grin*] try wrapping everything before the dot in `()` to force the replace to happen 1st ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey `'abc abc abc' -replace '\w+', ('$0 abc').ToUpper()` isn't working too. in more complex case i want to replace all matching substrings to it's uppercase variant with using `-replace` operator, not using `[regex]::replace()`

Comment: you put the 1st `(` in the wrong place ... you must wrap the WHOLE COMMAND that performs the replace and THEN use the `.ToUpper()` method on the resulting string. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Lee_Daily points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957351/why-actions-can-not-be-done-on-match-groups-when-using-replace-operator-in-power#comment109582742_61957351), the `.ToUpper()` call is executed *before* the string is passed to `-replace`.

If you want programmatic access to each substitute, use `[regex]::Replace()` directly:

```
[regex]::Replace('abc abc abc', '\w+', {"$($args[0].Value) abc".ToUpper()})
```

... or, if you're using PowerShell 6.1 or newer, `-replace` also supports a scriptblock for substitute evaluation:

```
'abc abc abc' -replace '\w+', {"$($_.Value) abc".ToUpper()}
```